# If coelocanths are more related to humans than groupers -does a Coelocanth's DNA literally have more sequences in common with a human than a grouper?

Tags: genetics, evolution, zoology

Would a coelocanth and a human still have more sequences in common than a coelocanth and a grouper? Would the coelocanth and human dna basically "look" more similar than either would to a ray-finned fish based on sequences?

Comment: This question is unclear.  Are you asking about comparing the coelacanth-to-human distance to the coelacanth-to-grouper distance, or are you comparing the coelacanth-to-human distance to the grouper-to-human distance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in virtually every way. In terms of pairwise distances, measured in percentages, humans and coelacanth are closer to one-another than coelacanth would be to any ray-finned fish. In terms of individual genes, there would be genes that humans and coelacanth share with their common ancestor, but are not found in any ray-finned fish. Remember, humans are bipedal terrestrial fish.

Comment: Thank you, it just seems so odd to me because groupers and coelocanths have such a similar morphology and lifestyle. Is this true of pretty much any more closely related taxa compared a less closely related outgroup? i.e. are the sequences always closer among more recently diverged groups compared to groups that diverged farther back?

Comment: @KarlKjer Good answer. Would be great to have the statistics for the # of pairwise differences between Coelacanth and a ray-finned fish species and between coelacanth and humans.